# Python script to get the total count of file types within a folder and write results into a file

Tags: python, file

How can I get the types of files within a folder? I need to get statistics about how many text files, binary files, image files, etc. and this information should be outputted into a text file.

Comment: in bash it would be much easier using a combination of `type`, `du` and `ls -1 | wc`. Does it really need to be python?

Answer (score 0):

As @Riccardo Petraglia mentioned in the comments, it would be easy to directly use the *nix command combinations. This can also be achieved using the python script below.

```py
import os

directory = input("Enter directory path: ")
extensions = []
for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    if extension:
        extensions.append(extension)

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")

for ext in extensions:
    ext_len = len(ext)
    file_count = len([f for f in os.walk(directory).__next__()[2] if f[-ext_len:] == ext])
    text_file.write("Total "+str(ext)+":"+str(file_count)+"\n")

print("Writing to file")
text_file.close()
```

Output:

```
Enter directory path: /Users/apple/Desktop
Stats
Total  .pdf : 1
Total  .py : 1
Total  .jpeg : 1
Total  .pem : 1
```